# Wordpress - Upgrading Disqus Comments causes 404 error, permission denied

Tags: database, wordpress, .htaccess, permissions, disqus

I'm trying to install Discus to my Wordpress website. When I go to the configuration page, I get the message "Upgrade Disqus Comments - You need to upgrade your database to continue." with a button to upgrade. When I click on upgrade, I get a 404 error page, with the following error message.

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access
>   /moshop/wp-admin/edit-comments.php on this server. Additionally, a 404
>   Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument
>   to handle the request.

I tried changing the permission of edit-comments.php from 664 to 777, even tried other combinations, but the problem is still present.

The .htaccess file in the wordpress's root directory is currently as follows.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /moshop/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /moshop/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Thanks in advance for any reply I can get.

Comment: Files should never be 777, if you want to give all write you use 666.  who is the owner of the file?

Comment: When I change that file to 666, I get Internal Server Error. How do I check the owner of the file? I'm hosting those wordpress files on NameCheap.

Comment: See what the error is first. When you get that error, check your logs to see what it says.